# Facebook SDK iOS - error while requesting publish permission after opening the session with read permissions

Tags: ios, permissions, facebook-permissions, facebook

My situation is as follows:

1. At first, user successfully logs into Facebook by requesting read permissions `user_friends` and `email`. I'm using `openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent` method to log in. All relevant user data and information about user's FB friends logged in are successfully handled
2. Then, when user taps a button, publish permission `publish_actions` needs to be requested. I've read that `reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions` method is deprecated, so I tried with recommended `requestNewPublishPermissions:defaultAudience:completionHandler:` method and I ended up with permanently getting error with message:

> FBSDKLog: FBSession: a permission request for publish or manage permissions contains unexpected read permissions

So, what am I doing wrong? Should I log out and then again log in by requesting only publish permission?
Or should I set some additional parameter on Application Dashboard? Should I somehow explicitly switch to sandbox since my app is already on AppStore?
(I'm aware that next version of my app has to be reviewed by FB due to requesting `publish_actions` permission.)

Comment: `(void)requestNewReadPermissions` – notice how it says _Read_ in there …?

Comment: I made a mistake in typing initial question, so I corrected it. I'm still getting same error. Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

> Use the following code after asking for permissions.

```
     if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
         // TODO: publish content.

     } else {
         FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
         [loginManager logInWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                fromViewController:self
                                           handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                               //TODO: process error or result.


                                           }];
     }
```